# restore all files from git repo with their respective commit's their sha1 or date appended to their filename?

Tags: git

Suppose I have a git repo that looks like this

```
commit #b97bd247a5d2530949c7acad0868e961c7777a28 Date: 2014-04-24 Time: 07:43
    file1.txt
    file2.txt

commit #4c1eb3b06dd4e51bf8541e67ec5dd8ad2744c695 Date: 2014-04-23 Time: 06:32
    file1.txt
```

I want to restore all files (both copies of `file1.exe`) and restore them in a directory structure like so:

```
file1_201404240743_b97bd247a5d2530949c7acad0868e961c7777a28.txt 
file2_201404240743_b97bd247a5d2530949c7acad0868e961c7777a28.txt 

file1_201404230632_4c1eb3b06dd4e51bf8541e67ec5dd8ad2744c695.txt
```

with their respective date and #sha1 appended to their names.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built in to git to do that, but it would be easy to do in a shell script.  For instance, suppose you wanted to `cd /tmp; mkdir restore; cd restore` and then do the above for some commits:

```
export GIT_DIR=/path/to/repo.git
for commit_id in $(git rev-list ...) # put specs for desired revs here
do
    cdate=$(git show -s --pretty=format:%cd $commit_id)
    echo "retrieve files from commit $commit_id on $cdate"
    for file in $(git ls-tree --name-only -r $commit_id); do
        git show ${commit_id}:${file} > ${file}_${cdate}_${commit_id}
    done
done
```

Note that this does not insert between "name" and "extension" part: you would get `file1.txt_201404230623_b97bd247a5d2530949c7acad0868e961c7777a28`, for instance.  For files in sub-directories the redirection (`> ...`) would fail because the directory does not already exist, too.  To fix these (if they need fixing), use `mkdir -p` to create directories as needed, and use regular expressions or some other similar technique to split up file names into "name" and "extension" parts, and insert the commit-date `$cdate` and commit-id `$commit_id`.